# How to handle pods shutdown gracefully in microservices architechture

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, deployment, microservices

I am exploring different strategies for handling shutdown gracefully in case of deployment/crash. I am using the Spring Boot framework and Kubernetes. In a few of the services, we have tasks that can take around 10-20 minutes(data processing, large report generation). How to handle pod termination in these cases when the task is taking more time. For queuing I am using Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

> we have tasks that can take around 10-20 minutes(data processing, large report generation)

First, this is more of a *Job/Task* rather than a *microservice*. But similar "rules" applies, the node where this job is executing might terminate for upgrade or other reason, so your *Job/Task* must be *idempotent* and be able to be *re-run* if it crashes or is terminated.

> How to handle pod termination in these cases when the task is taking more time. For queuing I am using Kafka.

Kafka is a good technology for this, because it is able to let the client Jon/Task to be *idempotent*. The job receives the data to process, and after processing it can "commit" that it has processed the data. If the Task/Job is terminated before it has processed the data, a new Task/Job will spawn and continue processing on the "offset" that is not yet committed.